# How can I get access to the app variable in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

How can I get an instance of `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` in a rails rake task.

I want to be able to call: `app.get '/'` like you can do in the rails console.

Answer (score 10):

```
 task :get_app => :environment do
    app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new Rails.application
 end
```